# failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse parameter override rule

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch gazebo with a specific rate with the following

```
gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_init.so --ros-args -p -publish_rate:=100.0
```

But I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1681606330.311154028] [rcl]: Failed to parse global arguments
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLInvalidROSArgsError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl: Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '-p -publish_rate:=100.0'. Error: Expecting token or wildcard, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/arguments.c:1138, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.14/src/rcl/arguments.c:325
```

I'm not sure if this is ROS or Gazebo related but I sure don't have a clue how to fix it (after a lot of internet searches)
Any help will be very appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414390/failed-to-initialize-rcl:-couldn%27t-parse-parameter-override-rule/) by [guidout](https://answers.ros.org/users/145435/guidout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, try removing the '-' before "publish_rate:=100.0"

```
gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_init.so --ros-args -p publish_rate:=100.0
```

---

Originally posted by [Then_CK](https://answers.ros.org/users/145214/then_ck/) with karma: 26 on 2023-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1